# Fedora 14 - hulu player does not load in firefox

Tags: flash, fedora-14, firefox-3.6, hulu

I have a fresh install of fedora 14 (64 bit) on my laptop. I installed the new 64bit flash using instructions from [this website](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Flash). Flash seems to work, I can load videos on youtube and they play just fine. In general, flash seems to work without a problem wherever I go. What I can't do is get the hulu player to load in firefox. It loads fine in Epiphany.
I couldn't get it to load with the standard 32 bit adobe flash either. If I switch to using Gnash, still nothing.

I am running Firefox version 3.6.4. I have adblock plus installed, but it is disabled for hulu.com
What settings do I need to have enabled or disabled for hulu player to load in firefox? Any other suggestions? anything I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried running Firefox in safe mode with all addons disabled and preferences set to defaults?

Comment: Does the desktop version work? http://www.hulu.com/labs/hulu-desktop-linux

Comment: @Adam, safe mode made no difference.

Comment: @tobylane, I have not tried that, but I will give it a shot.